# What's the unit of keep-alive in http?

Tags: http

```
Keep-Alive  115
Connection  keep-alive
```

The above appears in most request sent from my firefox,what's its unit?

Comment: Parsecs.  Oh wait, that's a unit of distance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.http.keep-alive.timeout):

> Amount of time *in seconds* to keep
>   keep-alive connections alive

Answer (score 0):

That header is actually invalid; see 
  https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=643352

That said, the unit is seconds.